# How to push data in mongodb array?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  imageUrl: String,
  category: String,
  price: Number,
  description: String,
  featured: {
    default: false
  },
  rating: [
    {
      userName: String,
      score: Number,
      comment: String
    }
  ]
});
```

And this is how I was trying to push data into my database.

```
app.route("/review").post(function(req, res) {
  const score = req.body.score;
  const comment = req.body.comment;

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    const review = {
      $push: {
        rating: {
          userName: req.user.fName,
          score: score,
          comment: comment
        }
      }
    };
    console.log(review, req.body.productName);
    Product.updateOne({ name: req.body.productName }, review, function(
      err,
      done
    ) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.redirect("/products");
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});
```

In the official documentation, it says that this is the way to push data in the MongoDB array. But still having no luck.
Help me to push reviews in the rating array field.
Thank You.

Comment: Any errors or logs you want to share?

Comment: It doesn't show any error, it goes to the else section & redirects to "/products".

Comment: what is this `userName: req.user.fName` ? it has to be from `req.body` !!

Comment: no, it's the name of the logged in user

Answer (score 1):

for my answer im using mongoose function `findOneAndUpdate` you can use updateOne instead , The writing to the database will be in a async function in order to not block the node process (will be alot faster).
Puting all the code in a try-catch block will allow you to control any errors if accrued.
You can read more about mongoose driver function and findOneAndUpdate here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/
more about async function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
app.route('/review').post(async function(req, res) {
//destructuring values from body-parser
  const { score, comment, productName } = req.body;

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    //creating the rating obj
    const rating = {
      userName: req.user.fName,
      score: score,
      comment: comment
    };
    console.log(review, productName);
   //setting it all in a try-catch block
    try {
      const product = await Product.findOneAndUpdate(
        {name: productName},
        { $set: { rating: rating } },
        { new: true }
      ).then(err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        return res.redirect('/products');
      });
      res.redirect('/login');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});
```

Hopefully this makes sense, good luck!